# Detecting when you're in/out of the main thread in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: multithreading, ios, xamarin.ios

Is there a way in Xamarin/MonoTouch to detect whether code is being called in the main thread?

I'm looking for something like the equivalent of Java's `EventQueue.isEventDispatchThread()` -- I've found in Swing programming it's handy to `assert` that from time to time (or sometimes to `assert` that it's not) -- making sure that models are consistently updated and read from the EDT, and that long-running calls don't block the UI.

I'd like to do the same in my MonoTouch app, to ensure that various bits of code are/aren't called from the UI, or wrapped in `InvokeOnMainThread`.

---

**Updated:** For anyone coming along later: [Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3973197/27358) answer from JP below . The Xamarin/MonoTouch equivalent is `NSThread.Current.IsMainThread`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check whether or not the current thread is the main thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546539/check-whether-or-not-the-current-thread-is-the-main-thread)

Comment: @bobobobo That question doesn't directly address the Monotouch syntax.

Comment: I didn't notice the [tag:monotouch].  Well, the answer ended up being the same.

Comment: @bobobobo I can de-accept the answer and answer it myself with the note I added at the end of the question, if that would make you happier.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't know much about Monotouch, but in iOS `+[NSThread isMainThread]` might be what you're looking for.

Occasionally when writing multithreaded code, I will put in an assert like this:

```
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"Method called using a thread other than main!");
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with `NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], errorDesc)` is that you BETTER be in the main thread when making this call. If you happen to be in a secondary thread and make the call then your application crashes! So it's kind of pointless.

It's better just to simply use `[NSThread isMainThread]` then assess the BOOL value it returns.

Comment: You're correct that the NSAssert in my answer will crash the app if it isn't run from the main thread. That's the purpose of using an NSAssert. During development, I use that assert to alert me if my code ever gets executed in the a non-main thread. You don't have to use the NSAssert from my answer -- you can do anything with that function. The NSAssert code is just an example of a possible use for the +[NSThread isMainThread] function. As a side note, your answer probably could have been a comment on my answer instead of a whole separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in Monotouch / Xamarin.ios

```
        if (NSThread.Current.IsMainThread)
        {
            //You are in the MainThread
        }
```

This check is very useful to avoid the error that might occur when trying to modify the UI from a background Thread. Something Like this can be done:

```
if (NSThread.Current.IsMainThread)
{
    DoSomething();
}
else
{
    BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => DoSomething());
}
```