# MonoTouch, how to tell if I am on UI thread

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.ios, ui-thread

The title says it all.

I have a generic function that is used to run actions on the UI thread. I want to simple invoke the action if I am already on the UI thread.

Is there a way to do this with MonoTouch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is `NSThread.IsMain`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962415/detecting-when-youre-in-out-of-the-main-thread-in-monotouch).

Comment: Sorry about the double post. I did search before I asked :)