# Pass data from view2 to view1 and update label

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have view1 and view2. In view2 I set up a delegate and enter some data. When I press the save button i view2 I am sent to view1. In view1 I get the data I entered in view2. BUT... when I try to update a label or button text in view1 with the data from view2 nothing happens. View1 is not updated.

This is the delegate function in view1 which should update the label:

```
func getCurrentContact(ViewController: ViewControllerSettings, data: (ContactDetails)) {
    NSLog("Yes, the delegate is called")

    self.lblContact1.text = data.name1 as? String
}
```

Anyone know why lblContact1.text is not updated? It just stay the same as on startup. The NSLog of data.name1 contains the correct data I entered in view2. Seems like view1 needs to be refreshed or something...

BTW; Does anyone know about a working swift project in GitHub or something that has navigation controller and a working delegate for sending data from view2 to view1? Would be outstanding...

Comment: why don't use pass data with prepareForSegue ?

Comment: Well, I like the idea of using delegates.

Comment: I also believe that you should use prepareForSegue when you want so send data from view1 to view2 and use delegates to send data back from view2 to view1

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your code like this to have some more success debugging this:

```
func getCurrentContact(ViewController: ViewControllerSettings, data: (ContactDetails)) {
    println("Yes, the delegate is called")

    if let name = data.name1 as ? String {
        println("Setting lblContact1 with \(name)")
        self.lblContact1.text = name
    } else {
        println("Either data was empty or data.name1 couldn't be extracted")
    }
}
```

If you're actually receiving `data.name1` as expected – then I would check that the the code you supplied is actually [running on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546539/check-whether-or-not-the-current-thread-is-the-main-thread).

Note that I've also replaced `NSLog` with `println` for a [number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951195/swift-print-vs-println-vs-nslog)

Comment: Yes, println("Setting lblContact1 with \(name)") returns the correct data. But  self.lblContact1.text is not updated. This is driving me nuts...